# Jupyter Notebook | Kernel stopped, will restart shortly | Error message when running notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter-kernel

I was running python code on Jupyter Notebook when the error saying the kernel has stopped, it will restart automatically.
There is an error specifically when running the tensorflow package. Updating the packages and jupyter notebook has not helped.

I tried updating all packages. I tried to restart the kernel. I tried reinstalling packages including the tensorflow package.

Comment: The error occurs in macOS

Answer (score 0):

I have uninstalled anaconda and reinstalled it again. This has fixed the problem. There is a new version that has correctly installed when I uninstalled the entire anaconda application.